# Creating custom geostamp in TerraGo toolbar?

Tags: geopdf

The blurb for the new 6.0 tool bar says it supports custom geostamps, but I can't find any info on how to create one.

Can anyone point me to the method for creating a custom geostamp that the toolbar will recognize?

So far, this is what I've figured out:

The geostamp files on Windows are in C:\Program Files\Common Files\TerraGo\GeoStamps

1. Each collection of stamps in the Geostamps menu corresponds to a pdf file in that directory.
2. Each file begins with a sequential letter of the alphabet. The installation has A thru E.
3. The name of the collection corresponds to the document name (which in the default files is the file name minus the first letter).
4. If you copy one of the existing collection files, rename the document (in Acrobat), rename the file to start with the next letter of the alphabet (F), you will see a new collection in the GeoStamps menu in Acrobat Reader.
5. The pdf file consists of one 8.5x11 page (apparently blank), plus a series of pages each .65" square containing a single symbol, which is a glyph from a font whose name essentially matches the collection name.
6. If you delete one (or more) of these pages, the file still works, but the corresponding stamp is missing.

And here's where it breaks down - 
8. If you add a page to this file, it does NOT appear as a symbol available to the Geostamp function in the toolbar. Interestingly, the added page does not break the collection, even if placed before the original pages. If you add markup to a symbol from the original document (like an arrow, for example), the markup appears in the symbol preview, but no in the symbol "stamped" onto the document.

I've checked all the document properties and can't find anything that seems out of the ordinary. But there must be something magic on the page to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this description on the TerraGo website. This only works in Acrobat Pro, not Reader. This is in the Knowledge base which is not findable with Google, nor can you produce an external link to the article as far as I can tell.

```
Can I create custom GeoStamps?   
Yes. Please follow the steps below to create you own custom GeoStamps:

1. Ensure that your "Commenting & Analysis" toolbar is visible
2. Click the drop-down arrow next to the Stamp Tool on the Commenting & Analysis toolbar.
**NOTE** This is not referring to the stamp tool on the GeoMark Toolbar.
3. Choose the "Create Custom Stamp..."
4. Browse to an Image to Import.
5. Give the Stamp a name & category if desired.

The new stamp PDF is created at C:\Documents and Settings\User
Name\Application Data\Adobe\Stamps and has an arbitrary name that
Adobe assigned.

6. Copy the PDF file to the following location:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\TerraGo\GeoStamps

7. Close the Adobe application to update your new GeoStamps.
8. Launch the Adobe application and open a GeoPDF file.

The GeoStamp tool now should display your custom GeoStamp under the
category you created.
```